# cassandra python driver automatically downgrade protocol_version doesn't work

Tags: python, cassandra

Here is my code:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
import cassandra
print('cassandra driver version: %s ' % str(cassandra.__version_info__))

# c = Cluster(['mgdevtestslc03-7583.slc07.dev.xxx.com'], protocol_version=3)
c = Cluster(['mgdevtestslc03-7583.slc07.dev.xxx.com'])
c.connect()
```

The above code will generate an exception as blow:

```
dbbox@ubuntu:~$ python  1.py
cassandra driver version: (3, 8, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 7, in <module>
    c.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1172, in connect
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2618, in connect
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2655, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.***.***.**': ConnectionException('Failed to initialize new connection to 10.***.***.**: Error from server: code=0000 [Server error] message="io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.apache.cassandra.transport.ProtocolException: Invalid or unsupported protocol version: 4"',)})
```

However, if I add the "protocol_version=3", it works.

Per [Python Cassandra Driver official document](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Cluster), protocal_version can be automatic downgraded,

> > > If not set in the constructor, the driver will automatically downgrade version based on a negotiation with the server

but why the automatic downgrade doesn't happen here?  I need this feature since I want to connect to many different version of cassandra cluster, so I don't want to set the protocal_version for every connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but are you attempting to connect to a Apache Cassandra 2.1.0-2.1.5 cluster?  There is a bug in those cassandra versions ([CASSANDRA-9451](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9451)) where it returns the wrong error response when it doesn't support a tried protocol version.

There was an issue opened up against the python driver to handle this more gracefully ([PYTHON-366](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-366)), but the decision was not to explicitly handle it since it affected outdated/old Cassandra version.   If you are running on a version of Cassandra between 2.1.0-2.1.5, it is probably worth considering updating to the latest 2.1 version (2.1.17 on this date) as there are likely known issues since those were early builds of 2.1.

Comment: this is exactly what is happening now!  My version is 2.1.2, but the issue CASSANDRA-9451 is fixed in 2.1.6.